# How can I make my dropdown disappear again using an if statement with css values as the condition?

Tags: javascript, html, css

The if statement isn't working as it should. I have put a css value as the condition . However, there seems to be something wrong with the  if statement's condition as my clicking "document" is not having the desired effect of executing "dontGetIt" function and thus making the dropdown display as "none".

HTML:

```
<div class="navs" id="menu">
            <p>MENU</p>
            <ul id="dropdown">
                <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
                <li><a href="blog.html">BLOG</a></li>
                <li><a href="books.html">BOOKS</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
.block {
    display: block !important;
}

#dropdown {
    display: none;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background: rgb(29, 18, 80);
    width: 6vw;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: left;
}
```

Javascript:

```
const menu = document.getElementById("menu");
const dropdown = document.getElementById("dropdown");

const getIt = () => {
    dropdown.classList.add("block");
}

const dontGetIt = () => {
    dropdown.classList.remove("block");
}

menu.onclick = getIt;

if (dropdown.style.display === "block") {
    alert("apple");
    dontGetIt;
}

else {
    alert("orange");
}
```

I want the dropdown to disappear again after I click the "document" (anywhere) once the dropdown appears after I click "menu".  However, even though clicking the menu turns the dropdown display to "block" in css, once I click the "document" again so the if statement can execute and the block display turns back to "none", this doesn't happen.

For some reason the if statement's condtion in () is only detecting "dropdown.style.display" if I apply it in javascript, but not if I do it through CSS.

Comment: The code all runs once.  Your onclick event handler runs due to the event it is bound to.  The other code will not be run because you "clicked somewhere else".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few different issues with toggling this, and as I commented, your assumption that code will run without a full page reload was incorrect.

In general, it is better to use console.log than to use alert for debugging.

The first issue is that you will not get the computed style in this circumstance, and need to utilize [getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle).

The 2nd is that you need some way of handling clicks on the body that aren't on the menu.

I tweaked the border styles to make it obvious to the boundary of the elements.

I added a body event listener, to handle clicks.  It's important to keep in mind that events from a child bubble up through all the parents/ancestors, so in a toggling situation, without preventing this, the parent eventlistener would immediately undo the addition of the class setting the menu display to block.

This code isn't meant to necessarily represent the best way of meeting your objectives, but does provide you a jumping off point for debugging and experimenting further.

```js
const menu = document.getElementById("menu");
const dropdown = document.getElementById("dropdown");

const getIt = (e) => {
  
    const style = window.getComputedStyle(dropdown);
    console.log(style.display);
    if (style.display !== "block") {
        dropdown.classList.add("block");
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    }  
}

const dontGetIt = (e) => {
    const style = window.getComputedStyle(dropdown);
    if (style.display === "block") {
        dropdown.classList.remove("block");
        console.log("Remove Block");
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    }  
}

document.body.addEventListener('click', dontGetIt);
menu.onclick = getIt;
```

```css
.vh {
  height: 100vh;
}

.block {
    display: block !important;
}

.navs {
  border: 2px solid green;
}

#dropdown {
    display: none;
    border: 1px solid red;
    background: rgb(29, 18, 80);
    width: 6vw;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<body class="vh">
    <div class="navs" id="menu">
        <p>MENU</p>
            <ul id="dropdown">
            <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
            <li><a href="blog.html">BLOG</a></li>
            <li><a href="books.html">BOOKS</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```